# Text Data is not getting Upload on MongoDB (For Registration)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mern

```
{
    "username":"suhail",
    "email": "Suhail@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456"
    
}
```

Here is the Error:

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 8000,
    "codeName": "AtlasError",
    "name": "MongoError"
}
```

I am Working on MERN Stack api and trying to send data to DB using JSON

i have done all my code correctly i have my connection with db all the routes, model and port # is ok, i am using from jason but file is not getting upload
someone please can help me

tried all the possible solution but not working

Comment: This is just a JSON document but no command., What do you try to do?

Comment: Sorry  actually this is not about file uploading, its a simple registration form using node and mongodb  i have written all the code properly, and trying to send this data in json format using POSTMAN, but its not getting save in db,

Comment: Obviously you have not written the code properly, otherwise it would work. Please show us the relevant code.